# How to prevent browser from adding contrast to button?

Tags: css, sass, google-chrome-devtools

This might be a silly question but how can I prevent browsers from adding contrast to my buttons? I can't find an origin to where this contrast is being added from upon inspecting in chrome, the code does not originate from my angular documents, so how can I prevent this? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fy5q.png)

Answer (score 0):

Browser isn't adding the contrast it is showing contrast checker result based on color combination.

Here is the detailed answer:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/Understanding_WCAG/Perceivable/Color_contrast